# Laravel form returning the wrong view

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller

I'm having a problem that I don't have a clue of how to solve it. I'm trying to make a form to insert data in the database. View where form is ubicated is returned by Laravel's default controller function `create`:

```
public function create()
    {
        return view("edicion-fosil");
    }
```

And edicion-fosil view with form is this:

```
@extends ('layouts.main-layout')
@section ('page-title', 'Fosilesleon')
@section ('content-area')
    <form action="fosil.store" method="get">
        <div id="inputs_generales_fosil">
            <div id="input_imagen_fosil">
                <img src="" alt="" id="imagen_fosil_edicion">
                <input type="file" id="imagen_fosil_input" name="imagen_fosil_input">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="input_mapa">

        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="guardar_fosil" value="Guardar"/>
    </form>
@endsection
```

The problem comes when I click on submit button. Instead returning `lista-fosiles` view, what controller store function is supposed to return, it's returning another view.

Controller store function is this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return view("lista-fosiles");
    }
```

View that it's supposed to return is this:

```
@extends ('layouts.main-layout')
@section ('page-title', 'Fosilesleon')
@section ('content-area')
    <?php
    //obtengo las distintas piedras, especies y edades
    $piedras = app('App\Http\Controllers\PiedraController')->getPiedras();
    $edades = app('App\Http\Controllers\EdadController')->getEdades();
    //$especies = app('App\Http\Controllers\EspecieController')->getEspecies();
    $nombres = app('App\Http\Controllers\EspecieController')->getNombres();
    $clases = app('App\Http\Controllers\EspecieController')->getClases();
    $filos = app('App\Http\Controllers\EspecieController')->getFilos();
    //dd($filos);
    ?>
    <div id="lista-fosiles-main">
        <form id="filtros-fosiles" action="#" method="fosiles/index">
            <div id="piedra">
                <label for="select-piedras">Piedra</label>
                <select id="select-piedras" name="select-piedras" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <option value="">Todas</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach($piedras as $piedra){
                        echo "<option value='".$piedra->id."'>".$piedra->nombre."</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="edad">
                <label for="select-edad">Edad</label>
                <select id="select-edad" name="select-especies" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <option value="">Todas</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach($edades as $edad){
                        echo "<option value='".$edad->id."'>".$edad->periodo."</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="nombre">
                <label for="select-nombre">Especie</label>
                <select id="select-nombre" name="select-nombre" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <option value="">Todas</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach($nombres as $nombre){
                        echo "<option value='".$nombre->nombre."'>".$nombre->nombre."</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="clase">
                <label for="select-clase">Clase</label>
                <select id="select-clase" name="select-clase" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <option value="">Todas</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach($clases as $clase){
                        echo "<option value='".$clase->clase."'>".$clase->clase."</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="filo">
                <label for="select-filo">Filo</label>
                <select id="select-filo" name="select-filo" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <option value="">Todos</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach($filos as $filo){
                        echo "<option value='".$filo->filo."'>".$filo->filo."</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="verificado">
                <label for="check-verificado">Verificado</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="check-verificado" name="check-verificado" onchange="this.form.submit()"/>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="fosiles-container">
            <?php
                $idEdad = "";
                $clase = "";
                $filo = "";
                $idUsuario = "";
                $idPiedra = "";
                $verificado = "";
                
                //$idEspecie = $_REQUEST["especie"];
                if(isset($_REQUEST["select-piedras"])){
                    $idPiedra = $_REQUEST["select-piedras"];
                }
                if(isset($_REQUEST["select-edad"])){
                    $idEdad = $_REQUEST["select-edad"];
                }
                if(isset($_REQUEST["check-verificado"])){
                    $verificado = $_REQUEST["check-verificado"];
                }
                $fosiles = app('App\Http\Controllers\FosilController')->getFosiles($idEdad, $idPiedra, $filo, $clase, $verificado, $idUsuario);
                foreach ($fosiles as $fosil){
                    $user = app('App\Http\Controllers\UserController')->getUserById($fosil->id_user);
                    $especie = app('App\Http\Controllers\EspecieController')->getEspecieById($fosil->id_especie);
                    echo ""?>
                        <x-fosil :fosil=$fosil :especie=$especie :user=$user></x-fosil>
                    <?php
                    ;
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

And view that is returning instead is:

```
@extends ('layouts.main-layout')
@section ('page-title', 'Fosilesleon')
@section ('content-area')
    <?php
    //print_r($_FILES);
    //inicializo el fósil obteniéndolo a partir de la id que me devuelve el método show de FosilController
    $fosil = app('App\Http\Controllers\FosilController')->getFosilById($fosil_id);
    //a partir de los datos del fósil, obtengo el usuario propietario, la piedra, la edad y la especie
    if($fosil != null){
        $user = app('App\Http\Controllers\UserController')->getUserById($fosil->id_user);
        $especie = app('App\Http\Controllers\EspecieController')->getEspecieById($fosil->id_especie);
        $piedra = app('App\Http\Controllers\PiedraController')->getPiedraById($fosil->id_piedra);
        $edad = app('App\Http\Controllers\EdadController')->getEdadById($piedra->id_edad);
        //esta variable guardará true si el usuario ha votado el fósil y false si no
        $votado = app('App\Http\Controllers\UsuariosvotoController')->votado(Auth::id(), $fosil_id);
    ?>

    <div id="ficha-fosil">
        <div id="datos-generales-fosil-main">
            <img src="{{$fosil->url_imagen}}" id="ficha-fosil-imagen" class="ficha-fosil-imagen" alt="imagen del fósil"  onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/default.png'">
            <div id="datos-generales-fosil"> 
                <div id="datos-generales">
                    <h2>{{$fosil->nombre}}</h2>
                    <h4>Ubicación:</h4>
                    <p>{{$fosil->direccion}}</p>
                    <h4>Publicado por:</h4>
                    <a href="" id="a-publicado-por" class="a-publicado-por">{{$user->name}}</a>
                    <?php
                    /*
                        if($fosil->verificado == 1){
                            echo "<p>Verificado <img src='/icons/check.png' height='16px' alt='verificado'/></p>";
                        }*/
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div id="votos">
                    <p><span class="bold big-font">{{$fosil->votos}}</span> usuarioshan verificado este fósil</p>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="datos-especificos-fosil">
            <div id="datos-especie">
                <h1>FÓSIL</h1>
                <h3>{{$especie->nombre}}</h3>
                <h5>Clase:</h5>
                <p>{{$especie->clase}}</p>
                <h5>Filo:</h5>
                <p>{{$especie->filo}}</p>
                <p>{{$especie->descripcion}}</p>
            </div>
            <div id="datos-piedra">
                <h1>PIEDRA</h1>
                <img id="imagen-piedra-ficha-fosil" src="{{$piedra->url_imagen}}" alt="{{$piedra->nombre}}">
                <h3>{{$piedra->nombre}}</h3>
                <h5>Procedencia</h5>
                <p>{{$piedra->procedencia}}</p>
                <h5>Edad</h5>
                <p>{{$edad->periodo}}</p>
                <p><em>({{$edad->anio_inicio}} - {{$edad->anio_fin}})</em></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    else{
        echo "<p>Something went wrong</p>";
    }
    ?>
    
@endsection
```

Sorry for the amount of code, just put it in case it's necessary. Also, sorry if it's an obvious mistake or if there are code that could be made of another better way, I'm getting started in Laravel. Thank you in advice :)

Comment: did you meant to put `action="{{route('fosil.store')}}"` instead of `action="fosil.store"` ?

Comment: Can you paste the routes also?

Comment: @Rurru Are you using blade only on the frontend??

Comment: @N69S yep, that was one of the problem. The other one is that route is "fosiles.store" instead "fosil.store". Answer if you want and I'll aprove your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There was two problems:

- Route is `fosiles.store` instead `fosil.store`
- `action` value is `{{route("fosiles.store")}}` (route() was missing)

Answered by @N69S